# erro : RegisterTcmMonitor from: $Proxy0 and skia: --- Failed to create image decoder with message 'unimplemented'

Tags: java, android

I have tried to many ways to set an image using URL in my Image 
View but, every time I got the same problem.
I'm using version 3.4.2 android studio.

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
 EditText etUrl;
 Button btClear, btSubmit;
 ImageView ivResult;
//This is my onCreate method
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    etUrl = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_url);
    btClear = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_clear);
    btSubmit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_submit);
    ivResult = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_result);

    btClear.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            etUrl.setText("");
            ivResult.setImageBitmap(null);
        }
    });

    btSubmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String url = etUrl.getText().toString();
            if(url.isEmpty()){
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Please Enter    Url...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else{
                LoadImage loadImage = new LoadImage(ivResult);
                loadImage.execute(url);
            }
        }
    });

}
```

//I have used this class to get image from the internet

```
private class LoadImage extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap>{

    ImageView imageView;
    public LoadImage(ImageView ivResult){
        this.imageView = ivResult;
    }

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... strings) {
        String urlLink = strings[0];
        Bitmap bitmap = null;

        try {
            InputStream inputStream = new URL(urlLink).openStream();
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return bitmap;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
        ivResult.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }
}
```

D/OpenGLRenderer: endAllActiveAnimators on 0x72d69c2500 (RippleDrawable) with handle 0x72e510fea0

D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using the platform default

I/DpmTcmClient: RegisterTcmMonitor from: $Proxy0

D/skia: --- Failed to create image decoder with message 'unimplemented'

W/System: A resource failed to call end.